# How do we turn down the insane brightness on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: brightness, 17.10, xrandr, wayland

`xrandr --brightness` doesn't work in Wayland.

Minimum brightness setting is scorching my eyes right now.

Comment: A quick look at the Arch wiki suggests 2 applications which should work on Wayland: brightnessctl  and acpilight. Might be well worth a look. Wiki page here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#Other_utilities

Comment: "applications which work on Wayland" is not the same thing as "applications which turn brightness below minimum and work on Wayland". I'm looking for a solution to this specific problem, not any old backlight app. The answer below talks about /sys/class/backlight, which does not solve the problem. As far as I can read, acpilight and brightnessctl are just front ends to the manual commands like sudo su -c "echo 90 >/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness", which does not address the problem. I need to be able to set brightness down to something like .45, the way we could with xrandr pre-Wayland.

Comment: i have my manual monitor brightness and contrast down to 0 and it is still bright.  the [brightness controller](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness) app stopped working for me after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, and Settings > Power > Screen brightness slider does not change brightness :/

Comment: Ubuntu has this page, but none of the directions work unfortunately:  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html  There have been several software updates since upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 but they haven't solved the brightness problem.

Comment: `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf:WaylandEnable=false` is a way to switch to gdm on 17.10, where brightness controls work !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like there is no true solution.

Best alternatives are to use @Rober Riedl's comment and switch to gdm with /etc/gdm3/custom.conf:WaylandEnable=false, or wait and upgrade to 18.04, which will leave wayland because of its many problems.

I also installed some nighttime dimmers to somewhat reduce the brightness, but they're far from properly addressing this problem, too.