# Brightness Control Issue on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I am not able to change brightness on Ubuntu 17.10. Keywords function are also not functioning. There is no option of brightness control system on a Ubuntu 17.10. How to change brightness??

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966557/how-do-we-turn-down-the-insane-brightness-on-ubuntu-17-10) might be worth a look

Comment: Are you using Wayland or Xorg as display server?